# XSD random order of 2 elements, while element1 is only allowed a total of 3 times and element2 has no such restriction

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I am quite new to XML and XSD, and I need to be able to check for what I asked in the title.

for example element1,element2,element1,element2,element2,element2,element2,element1 is valid.

but: element1,element2,element2,element1,element1,element1 is not, because element1 occured more than 3 times.

It is important, that the order of those two types of elements can be completely random.

What I came up with doesn't quite work:

```
                                    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                        <xsd:element name="element2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                            <xsd:element name="name"  type="xsd:string"/>
                                            <xsd:attribute name="temp" type="xsd:string"/>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="element1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3">
                                            <xsd:element name="name"  type="xsd:string"/>
                                            <xsd:attribute name="temp" type="xsd:string"/>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                    </xsd:sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a content model equivalent to

```
E2* (E1 E2*){0, 3}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick reply. I forgot to mention in my post, that element1 needs to be present atleast once. So basically E1: 1-3 times, E2: as often as we want (in any order)

Comment: Then you just need to change the `{0, 3}` to `{1, 3}`.